# I cant read from files to confirm username

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to make a program where you have to login with username (to make it simple i'm first using username, i will add password some time later) 
To make it work i want to write the username to a file (which i will encrypt later) and when you want to login, it will check through the file if the username is in fact correct. But when i type in a faulty username, it automatically logs in and dosen't ask to make a new account. Same thing if i do login with the correct username. What am i doing wrong?
(i'm pretty new and this is my first half-decent program so please don't be too harsh if i'm doing something obviously wrong.)

Soo. I did some of those things i understood. This is what i got now:
BUT, now it won't write the new username to the Usernames_and_passwords file.
i am incredibly confused...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string user_input;
string birth_year;
string user_age;
string current_user_profile, current_user_password;
string username, password;
string newprofile;
string makenewusername, makenewpassword;

void TalkToAi() { //VOID TALKTOAI
    while (true) {
        cout << "write something: ";
        cin >> user_input;
            transform(user_input.begin(), user_input.end(), user_input.begin(), ::tolower); //TRANSLATES ALL UPPERCASE LETTERS TO LOWER CASE SO THE SYSTEM CAN UNDERSTAND!
        cout << user_input << "\n"; //###FOR TESTING PORPOSES!!!###

        //IF LIBRARY!

        if (user_input == "what's my age?" || user_input == "count my age" || user_input == "whats my age?") {
            //###CONTINUE HERE!!!###
        }

    }
}

void StartUp() { //VOID UPONSTARTUP (WHAT TO DO, ALSO READS DIFFRENT PROFILES AND PASSWORDS FOR LOGIN)
    cout << "what profile should i load?" << "\n" << "profile name: ";
    cin >> current_user_profile;

    fstream Myfile;
    Myfile.open("Usernames_and_passwords.txt");

    if (Myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline (Myfile, username) ) {
            if (username == current_user_profile) {
                cout << "\n" << "Hello, " << username << "\n";
                break;
                }
                }
        if (username != current_user_profile) {
            cout << "wrong username or username unfortunately not found.\n";
            cout << "shall i create a new profile? Yes/No: ";
            cin >> newprofile;
            if (newprofile == "Yes" || newprofile == "yes") {
                cout << "new profile username: ";
                cin >> makenewusername;
                Myfile << makenewusername << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments like "//CALLS VOID STARTUP" are pretty worthless, as we can already see that by just reading the code. Add comments and documentation for things that aren't obvious.

Comment: As for your problem, I recommend some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and that you simply sit down and think a little while about your design and the implementation of it.

Comment: ok, ill try to figure it out, And i know those are a bit useless. But i just don't want to do beginner mistakes by making the code very hard to understand.

Comment: Some things to think about for the problem in this questions: 1) What should you do when you match the user-name in the file? Should you really continue reading from the file? 2) Should you really check if the user isn't found *inside* the loop? 3) Should you really write to the file in the middle of it? Perhaps you should open it twice (once for reading, and once for writing)? 4) Don't use global variables. Especially if they aren't even shared between functions.

Comment: Does it actually print hello if you enter the correct username? Have you tried debugging the code step by step to see exactly what is happening?

Comment: @GottaAimHigherPal I would recommend you start with easier exercises, to learn the basics about functions and basic code organization. Then you can go on managing files etc.

Comment: @GottaAimHigherPal Swearing and begging for source code won't work here. You've got to aim higher, pal.

Comment: nice one ;). But i really don't get it, more specifically. What is wrong? the loop? could i get links to websites that can show me how to easily compare strings between user input and the file until it finds the right username?

Answer (score 0):

It won't write to the file because once you finish reading the file with getline(), the eof flag will be set. You need to open the file using:

`Myfile.open("Usernames_and_passwords.txt",fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);`

This tells the program to open the file for reading and writing. fstream::app tells the program to append text to the end of the file.

Then, in order to reset once an eof has been hit you can do

```
Myfile.clear();
Myfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

This will clear the eof flag, and move the pointer back to the beginning of the file. 
After this you can write to the file.

A few other remarks:
Your loop is broken: it won't work if the file is empty and it will write duplicate usernames if the entered username is on the second line instead of the first.

Here is a modified version of your function:

```
void StartUp() { //VOID UPONSTARTUP (WHAT TO DO, ALSO READS DIFFRENT PROFILES AND PASSWORDS FOR LOGIN)
    cout << "what profile should i load?" << "\n" << "profile name: ";
    cin >> current_user_profile;

    fstream Myfile; 
    Myfile.open("Usernames_and_passwords.txt",fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);   

    if (Myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline (Myfile, username) ) {
            if (username == current_user_profile) {
                cout << "\n" << "Hello, " << username << "\n";
                return;
                }
        }

        cout << "wrong username or username unfortunately not found.\n";
        cout << "shall i create a new profile? Yes/No: ";
        cin >> newprofile;
        if (newprofile == "Yes") {
            cout << "new profile username: ";
            cin >> makenewusername;         
            Myfile.clear();
            Myfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);                  
            Myfile << makenewusername << endl;  
        }   
    }
}
```

I would also suggest to let StartUp return a boolean value on whether or not the operation succeeded, so you can decide to terminate the program. E.g. if the user entered "No".

Comment: _"You are not closing the file once you are done with it"_ Not true at all; [the `.close()` call is redundant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/close) and the file will be closed when the stream goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for you're help. I didn't know the community was so helpful!